# how can you make li click dynamically when last was also created dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

The list was dynamically produced as follow;

```css
function addItemsToList(name, surname, location, town, userid, email) {
  var listEmployeesInfo=document.getElementById('mListHeader');
  listEmployeesInfo.innerHTML='Province Retrieved: '+(location)+' | Town: '+(town);
  var ul=document.getElementById('list');
  var header=document.createElement('h2');
  var _name=document.createElement('li');
  var _surname=document.createElement('li');
  var _userid=document.createElement('li');
  var _email=document.createElement('li');
  _name.innerHTML='Name : '+name;
  _surname.innerHTML='Surname : '+surname;
  _userid.innerHTML='User ID : '+userid;
  _email.innerHTML='Email : '+email;
  ul.append(header);
  ul.appendChild(_name);
  ul.appendChild(_surname);
  ul.appendChild(_userid);
  ul.appendChild(_email);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="column right" style="overflow-y: auto; height: 500px; " id="listDiv">
  <h3 id="mListHeader" style="padding-left: 10px;">Employee List Viewed</h3><br>
  <button id="btn-Update">Update</button>
  <ul class="empList" id="list">
  </ul>
</div>
```

How can I make li elements clicker-able? because I want to able to update name, surname, id and email of clicked group?

Comment: Can you please update your snippets into a single [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? This way it's easier to understand and debug.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Click event on newly created UL LI element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47565554/click-event-on-newly-created-ul-li-element)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use event delegation on the parent list

```
var ul = document.getElementById('list');
ul.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
   var tgt = evt.target;
   if (tgt.matches('li')) {
      console.log(tgt.textContent);
   } 
});
```

so you capture the click event on the [bubbling phase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing) with only one event handler, no matter if the list-items are already in the document or if they have been dynamically created.

As a side note you can't append a header as a child of a list (`ul.append(header);`)

Comment: Thanks. I'm new in javascrip. Let me see what that evt returns because I wamt to update the contents of that clicked list element. I'll tell you how it went. Thanks again.

Comment: Fabrizio you're a star. It work I just needed to remove the ")" on line 6.

Comment: Fabrizio you're a star. It is working, I just needed to remove the ")" on line 6. '})'. I get clicked list data but now I actually wanted to pick name, surname and email because I want to update this data of my Firebase database so I'm not sure how to further build on top this single click event to get the others or may be I should introduce a popup dialog. Any ideas.. Thanks again man.

Comment: @Sfili_81 My apologies those snippets are not really going to make that much sense. In the first place I shouldn't have posted this with snippets. All the different section comes from HTML and Script files. Hope you get it.